# condensing rewrite rules in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

These are my rewrite rules. The first rule is problematic and its sortof what I'm trying to achieve. The last four work but that's an overkill.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/^.]+)/([0-9]{4})([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})/p(([0-9]{1,5})-([0-9]{1,3}))?$ /test2-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6


RewriteRule ^([^/^.]+)/([0-9]{4})([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})/p([0-9]{1,5})-([0-9]{1,3})$ /test-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6
RewriteRule ^([^/^.]+)/([0-9]{4})([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})/p([0-9]{1,5})-$ /test-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5
RewriteRule ^([^/^.]+)/([0-9]{4})([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})/p([0-9]{1,5})$ /test-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5
RewriteRule ^([^/^.]+)/([0-9]{4})([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})/p$ /test-$1-$2-$3-$4
```

What I'm trying to do is use one rewriterule instead of four to handle URLs in the following formats:

```
http://example.com/word/####wor##/p#-###
http://example.com/word/####wor##/p#-
http://example.com/word/####wor##/p#
http://example.com/word/####wor##/p
```

Is there any way I can condense my rewriterules to just one instead of four?

I'll add more info later if necessary.

Comment: Just for clarification: in the URLs you want to match against, the `#` stands for any digit, `wor` could be any 3 letters (and not just those three, in this exact order), but `p` should always match against the letter `p`?

Answer (score 0):

There might be more elegant ways to solve this, but the following should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/^.]+)/([0-9]{4})([a-z]{3})([0-9]{2})/p(?:([0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1})-|([0-9]{1})-([0-9]{3})){0,1}$ /test-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8 [L,NC]
```

To break it down:

The first part is what you've been doing so far. It covers capture results `$1` to `$4`.

Then comes `/p`, which is followed by one big group that's split into several alternations separated with the pipe character `|`. One of the options contained in this group should match either zero or one time(s) `/p(?:...|...|...){0,1}`.

The `?:` at the beginning of this group signifies that the group as a whole should not be used for capturing as you don't necessarily want to capture the end result (like when it contains an `-`), so we'll stick to only capturing the sub groups that are relevant. This also means that when counting your capture groups to know which translates to which of your variables (`$1`, `$2` etc.), you will not count this group.

The alternations match the 3 variations you provided for your URLs where the `/p` is followed by something else:

```
([0-9]{1})
([0-9]{1})-
([0-9]{1})-([0-9]{3})
```

Note that in your end result `/test-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8` not all variables might match something, depending on the pattern of your URL. Some might remain empty.

Comment: @Mike, did this solve your problem? If so, could you accept the answer so your question gets marked as resolved?